# JDBC, query retorna false mas salva no banco

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou executando a seguinte função em java:

```
public boolean insert(User user) throws SQLException{
        String sql = "insert into usuarios (nome, email, senha) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement instruction = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        instruction.setString(1, user.getName());
        instruction.setString(2, user.getEmail());
        instruction.setString(3, user.getPassword());

        boolean result = instruction.execute();
        instruction.close();
        return result;
    }
```

o problema é que ele sempre retorna false em `instruction.execute()` mas se faço um select em usuários, aparece que ele foi cadastrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ricardo,

Certamente retornará *false*, pois o `execute()` não é específico para inserção de dados apesar de funcionar também. Você deveria ter usado o `executeUpdate()`, pois, no caso, comando de *INSERT* é considerado como *update*.

- `executeUpdate()` = comandos DML (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE).
- `executeQuery()` = recuperação de dados (SELECT).
- `execute()` = comandos DDL (CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE ...).

Se formos olhar a documentação do Java a respeito do [PreparedStatement#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29):

> Returns: true if the first result is a ResultSet object; **false if the
>   first result is an update count** or there is no result.

Perceba o que marquei em negrito acima. No caso de você estar realizando *INSERT* através do `execute()`, o resultado será falso pois o *INSERT* é entendido como um operação de "*update*".

Comment: Entendi, mas o executeUpdate() me retorna um int...

Comment: Isso, esse int indica o número de registros inseridos, que no caso deverá ser 1 para casos de inserção bem sucedida. Caso a inserção tenha falhado, ele irá retornar algo diferente disso, que é o 0. Qualquer coisa dê uma olhada aqui: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: Consegui, Obg !

Answer (score 0):

Isto ocorre pois o método `execute` da classe `PreparedStatement` retorna `true` se o primeiro resultado é um objeto do tipo `ResultSet` e `false` se o primeiro resultado é um `contador de update` ou nenhum resultado.

Ao persistir em seu código o retorno será um `contador de update` informando a quantidade de registros inseridos.

Fonte: [Documentação Oracle Java SE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute())